# Visual Studio 2015 debugger closes application

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

Once I start any application from VS with debugger on Any CPU or x86, application exits immediately with exitcode 0. It works fine if I compile application for x64.

I have tried:

- Reset VS Settings
- Reinstall (repair) .NET
- Check paths
- Clean/Rebuild solution
- Reboot PC

But it did not help.

What could be the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Is it open in another visual studio somewhere else?

Comment: @Aaron, no, there is only one instance running, I have also tried rebooting PC and running it after reboot - still the same issue.

Comment: do you have 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: @FahadJameel, I have x64 Windows, however, it worked without issues before.

Comment: @Puyebu， if you run your app using "start without debugging" with Any CPU or X86, how about the result? Or debug your app with breakpoint, it seems that the exitcode 0 is normally for debugging some project types like the Console app or others which were closed automatically, we could modify the code or add the breakpoints. If still no help, view the detailed output window, maybe it showed detailed output messages.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, if I use debugger for x86 or Any CPU project - then it exists with no messages regarding errors. If I run them without debugger, they run fine. If I run x64 with debugger - it works fine. I am using WinForms.

Comment: @Puyebu, whether all WinForms apps have the same issue or just the specific one? If you change the .NET Framework version for this project, how about the result? Or enable the Exception settings under Debug->Windows, and then debug it again, we have to make sure that no exception was threw.  In addition, please make sure that your app was in Debug mode after you change the target, you could also compare the .xxproj file, or view the Build->configuration Manager window, find the differences.

Comment: It was something with regsvr proccess. Once I closed it, everything started working normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in running regsvr process. 
Once I shut down the proccess, debugging started working without issue.

Comment: glad to know that you have resolved this issue, you could mark it as the answer.

Comment: I thought it was about two days before I could accept my own answer. Accepted it, thanks for noticing.